# FaceBook SDK import in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, sdk, r.java-file

Sort of a amateur question, but i have been trying to import facebook sdk in to eclipse so that later i can use it as a library in another project. At first i was faced with a lot of errors, but i solved  a lot of them by figuring out how to add the external libraries. But only a few issues which are still left are:

1. Error on Import com.facebook.R (cannot be resolved)
2. Error on R.style.com_facebook_loginview_default_style (R cannot be resolved)

Need help, as i could not find any thing regarding this issue. How to make this go away.

Answer (score 0):

It means the facebook SDK project cannot generate the R.java file(check the gen folder in your project)

Usually it's your project API version is not right, or you could post your error message(look at console window and post here what it says)

Comment: Thanks yeah that worked... Changed the version and the problem was solved.